# Want to perform multiple arithmetic operator at once in C# Calculator

Tags: c#

I have made calculator using C# which woks pretty good for normal use case but when I can only give two numbers as input and then press Equal Button and it shows result and after that I have to input any other number to perform further operations.

Suppose I have to perform: `100 - (20 + 25)`.

It's working like:

```
Step 1: 20 + 25 = 45
```

then

```
Step 2: 100 - 45 = 55
```

Where as I want multiple operations at once like:

```
100 - (20 + 25) = 55
```

Comment: Please remove the three tags that are nothing to do with this question. You will be left with only the  C# tag.

Comment: Search on-line for the term "expression tree"

Comment: what do you mean - multiple operations at once? Do you mean in parallel